# SharePoint Event Receiver does not fire after deployment

Tags: event-receivers, solution-deployment

I have created a simple SharePoint 2013 solution and added event receiver. When I am in visual studio, i hit F5, solution is deployed and event receiver works. However, when I publish the solution (.wsp), add it into solutions, activate the solution, activate the feature in the site collection admin, it just does not work.

I found out, that after I use "deploy" in VS13, then event receiver starts working just like it was working during debugging. Do you have any idea why please? :) I am banging my head what could be wrong...

thank you very much

Here is my very crude code:

```
 public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdded(properties);
        base.EventFiringEnabled = false;

        String curListName = properties.ListTitle;

        if (curListName == "ListOfAddedItem")
        {
            string internalName = properties.ListItem.Fields["Title"].InternalName;

            //Turn off event firing during item update
            base.EventFiringEnabled = false;

            SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
            item[internalName] = "E:" + item[internalName];


            //getting second web
            string siteUrl = "issserver/sites/devsite";



            try
            {
                SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl);

                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPList list = web.Lists["OtherList"];

                    list.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.ID].ReadOnlyField = false;

                    SPListItem Item = list.Items.Add();
                    Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.ID] = item["ID"];
                    Item["Title"] = item["Title"];
                    Item.Update();

                    list.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.ID].ReadOnlyField = true;
                }  
            }
            catch {
                item[internalName] = "cannot connect to the site";
            }


            item.Update();

            //clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            base.EventFiringEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you activated features related to your WSP solutions in site and site collection features?

Comment: Hi Dikesh, yes I did. I have attached two screenshots to my original post. this is very strange.

Comment: What about site features? Have you added that event receiver in feature? Don't get me wrong. Just double check it.....:)

Comment: it is not shown in site features as the solution scope is set to site - activation for site and all other subsites.

Comment: Please restart the SharePoint timer service & rest IIS before deployment of your solution.... It will work...

Comment: Hi Hardik , I can do that on my development server but i cannot do that on deployment farm because I do not have access to the central administration. is there any other reason, why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found an error. My testing enviroment was local server and deployment server was office 365 sharepoint. i tried the simple code and it started to work. I guess i will have to start logging what exactly caused it :)

this code worked:

```
     public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdded(properties);
        SPListItem _item = properties.ListItem;
        _item["Title"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        _item.Update();
    }
```